# Potential bug on Highchart bubble graph (hover fill color)

Tags: highcharts

Please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muswoh4k/).

For some reason the fillColor on hover behaves in a strange way (try to hover on any of the bubbles in the lower part). Even bubbles belonging to the same series get a different hover color.

As I need to have a halo coherent with the color of the bubble I do something like:

```
    states: {
            hover: {
                halo: {
                    attributes: {
                        fill:       Highcharts.Color(colors.BottomRight).setOpacity(0.5).get('rgba')
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

And it works for the halo. I never specify the hover fillColor. I also tried to specify it but it ignores me.

The data series are copy paste, so no error is possible between them (then I changed the data of course).

I suspect this a bug. Can anybody confirm?

Thank you!

SN

Comment: Related to `threshold` somehow. Setting `threshold: -10` avoids the problem in your example.

Comment: Thank you! It indeed solved the issue. I still think this behavior is strange to say the least, as I never specified a negative color :/

Comment: This is bug in Highcharts, indeed. It should be already fixed on the bugfix branch: http://jsfiddle.net/muswoh4k/2/ See [discussion](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4508) and related ticket.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!